# Hibernate load another column related to a foreign key

Tags: java, hibernate, foreign-keys

I am having these two relations:

```
ACTION(ID, AMOUNT, BY) 
USER(ID, NAME)

//BY is a foreign key that references USER(ID)
```

In my JAVA project I am having something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table("action")
class Action{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id")
  private int id;

  @Column(name = "amount")
  double amount;

  @Column(name="by")
  int userId;

  @???
  String userName;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table("user")
class User{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id")
  private int id;

  @Column(name = "name")
  String name;
}
```

What I want to know is how to link my Action class so that it loads the correct `userName` which is referred by `by` (userId) column?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would you keep the username field in Action class? Foreign keys help you normalise data and the above models is just not following up that principle. It's duplication of data(name). You can have the whole user object lazily loaded in Action class and it can then give you the user name

Comment: `by` is the foreign key then map @OneToOne with user means add User in Action

Comment: @RahulVedpathak  How to have the whole User object loaded in Action? to which column it will be mapped, and will I have to keep the userId if I include the whole User object in Action class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `User` in Action class and @JoinColumn with `by`

```
class Action{
  ...
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "by")
  User user;
}

class User{
 ...
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<Action> actions;
}
```

Comment: When I insert a new Action with an embedded new User, does the new user will be automatically inserted?

Comment: No, as far as I recall, you have to persist first the user and then an entity referencing it.

Comment: Depends if you use bidirectional relation then it will work but you have to both way sync.

Comment: I don't see how will I use a bidirectional relation in my case, can you give some insights please?

Comment: A User can have many actions or one only? Then it will be more clear relation is OneToMany or OneToOne

Comment: Is it normal that a User has a Singleton Action attribute while it is a OneToMany dependency?

Answer (score 1):

You're already keeping the `userId` information in your `Action` class - so either remove the userName field, and when you need that information fetch it separately based on the userId. So your Repository or DAO class can expose a method named: `findUsernameBy(int userId)` returning a String.

Another way is to implement OneToOne relation with a user entity:

```
@Entity
@Table("action")
class Action{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id")
  private int id;

  @Column(name = "amount")
  double amount;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinCoumn(name="by")
  private User user;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps @JoinCoumn(name="userId") should be @JoinCoumn(name="by")?

Answer (score 1):

If you have many actions per user, replace:

```
@Column(name="by")
int userId;

@???
String userName;
```

with

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "by")
private User user;
```

You can also add:

```
// Cascade to propagate wanted actions to many side
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Action> actions;
```

to your `User` entity to have birectional mapping. So to list all Users actions. In addition to adding to cascade and adding action to users actions you need to set action's user or saving will not work correctly. In other words you need to set both ends of mapping correctly.

Comment: Thks! Why did you use ManyToOne instead of OneToOne in the first suggestion (other answers used OneToOne)?

Comment: I didn't understand to what does 'user'  refer in : @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")

Comment: It is because yout table USER does not have any direct key to ACTION.  So typically  this can be also ManyToOne:  there can be many ACTIONs that have same USER.id. (by). mappedBy just tells that the field name in many side (ACTION) has the user in field name "user".

Comment: I figured out 'user' reference. With this, when I insert a new User with new embedded Actions, hibernate will automatically insert those new actions?

Comment: Edited comment: and actually mappedBy= is not be necessarily needed here but without it there will be a separate mapping table. Also all the `@Column` name declarations are not needed because they are all the same as field names. `@JoinColumn` is needed because JPA would otherwise default to "user_id".

Comment: I the last sentence, I think you mean JPA would use "action_id" (not "user_id")  ?

Comment: The join column is in the ACTION. So it would be user_id by default, referreing to USER.